# How can I efficiently remove zeroes from a (non-sparse) matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, performance, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix:

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 5 0 7 0];
```

I need to remove all of the zeroes, like so:

```
x = [1 1 5 7];
```

The matrices I am using are large (1x15000) and I need to do this multiple times (5000+), so efficiency is key!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way:

```
x(x == 0) = [];
```

**A note on timing:**

As mentioned by [woodchips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738438/removing-zeros-from-a-matrix-not-sparse/738861#738861), this method seems slow compared to the one used by [KitsuneYMG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738438/removing-zeros-from-a-matrix-not-sparse/738484#738484). This has also been noted by Loren in one of her [MathWorks blog posts](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/09/25/timing-extraction-of-parts-of-an-array/). Since you mentioned having to do this thousands of times, you may notice a difference, in which case I would try `x = x(x~=0);` first.

**WARNING:** Beware if you are using non-integer numbers. If, for example, you have a very small number that you would like to consider close enough to zero so that it will be removed, the above code won't remove it. Only *exact* zeroes are removed. The following will help you also remove numbers "close enough" to zero:

```
tolerance = 0.0001;  % Choose a threshold for "close enough to zero"
x(abs(x) <= tolerance) = [];
```

Comment: This fails on negative numbers
Try `abs(x)<= tolerance`

Comment: The x <= tolerance would exclude negative floating point numbers.  You would probably need to expand the comparison to be x >= tolerance and x <= tolerance.  The operator for logical and in matlab escapes me at this moment.

Comment: I corrected the answer to remove any value close enough to zero from either the negative or positive direction.

Answer (score 11):

Just to be different:

```
x=x(x~=0);
```

or

```
x=x(abs(x)>threshold);
```

This has the bonus of working on complex numbers too

Answer (score 11):

Those are the three common solutions. It helps to see the difference.

```
x = round(rand(1,15000));

y = x;

tic,y(y==0) = [];toc

Elapsed time is 0.004398 seconds.

y = x;

tic,y = y(y~=0);toc

Elapsed time is 0.001759 seconds.

y = x;

tic,y = y(find(y));toc

Elapsed time is 0.003579 seconds.
```

As you should see, the cheapest way is the direct logical index, selecting out the elements to be retained. The find is more expensive, since matlab finds those elements, returning a list of them, and then indexes into the vector.

Comment: Wow! Are those numbers right? I could have sworn that "y(y==0)=[];" and "y=y(y~=0);" were comparable to each other speed-wise. I'll have to check my numbers again.

Comment: Never mind... I just found a blog post by Loren at the mathworks that addresses exactly this problem, and it seems to agree with your numbers.

Comment: @gnovice Note that you can now use `[~, ~, y] = find(y)` which should give similar performance to the solution with logical indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way

y = x(find(x))

I'll leave it to you to figure out the relative efficiency of the various approaches you try -- do write and let us all know.

Answer (score 2):

Though my timing results are not conclusive to whether it is significantly faster, this seems to be the fastest and easiest approach:

```
y = nonzeros(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 5 0 7 0]
y = [0 2 0 1 1 2 5 2 7 0]
```

Then     x2 and     y2 can be obtained as:

```
x2=x(~(x==0 & y==0))
y2=y(~(x==0 & y==0))

x2 = [0     1     1     0     5     0     7]
y2 = [2     1     1     2     5     2     7]
```

Hope this helps!