# Deleting rows containing zero

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find a better way for deleting rows out of some vectors that contain a zero. What I am doing right now is the following code:

```
i = 1;
while i <= length(JAbs)
    if JAbs(i) == 0
        JAbs(i) = [];
        JX(i) = [];
    else
        i = i+1;
    end
end
```

I suppose there is an easier way and would greatly appreciate any help.

Best regards,
Achim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing zeros from a matrix - Not Sparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738438/removing-zeros-from-a-matrix-not-sparse)

Comment: no duplicate as my problem was how to do it not only for one vector but for multiple vectors where the same row needs to be removed. see my example code where both JAbs and JX get the row removed.

Comment: It's still the same operation, except on two vectors: `goodRows=JAbs~=0;JAbs=JAbs(goodRows);JX=JX(goodRows);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Learn to use vector operations.
2. Learn to avoid loops, especially bad are loops that chance the size of your arrays in each pass.
3. Learn to use boolean indexing rather than find. It is faster.

   X(X == 0) = [];

Comment: this code doesn't preserve the matrix form. It makes a one long line output? Why?

Answer (score 10):

```
>> X=[1 2 3; 3 2 0; 1 2 3;0 3 2]
X =
     1     2     3
     3     2     0
     1     2     3
     0     3     2
```

removing rows with zeros

```
X(sum((X==0),2)>0,:) = []
```

the result:

```
X =
     1     2     3
     1     2     3
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if MATLAB allowed negative indices to indicate removal, the way **R** does  :-(