# Matlab: is removing rows/columns from a matrix expensive?

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, memory

Appending rows/columns to a matrix in MATLAB seems quite something to consider. For example, when I tried appending a column to a matrix `A` which has many rows and many columns, like

```
A = [A, added_col]
```

Matlab will warn me that since this has to make a copy of A in the memory, I'd better use pre-allocation for speed. This is understandable, because the underlying data in `A` occupies a contiguous block of memory.

My question is, will *removing* rows/columns cause similar issues? For example, to remove the second row of `A`:

```
A(2,:) = []
```

Is this operation in-place or not? I really feel unsure, since for one thing it doesn't seem to make any new room for data in the memory, and for another, the rows of `A` will be stored non-contiguously (since row 2 is removed).

So what will happen internally? And is this operation efficient enough to use in practice? Thanks!

---

Just tested it with a complexity of `100000`:

```
clc; clear;
N = 100000;
A = zeros(N, 3);

t1 = tic;
for ii = 1:N
    A(ii, :) = [1 2 3];
end
t2 = toc;
```

And

```
clc; clear;
N = 100000;
A = zeros(N, 3);

t1 = tic;
for ii = (N-1):-1:2
    A(ii, :) = [];
end
t2 = toc;
```

Results: 0.009s for the first (modifying preallocated matrix) and 53.429s for the second (removing rows from a matrix). I think this basically settles this question: **NO, removing rows/columns from a matrix is NOT efficient to use**, since it definitely involves deepcopying data and reallocating memory.

Also, removing *columns* instead of rows isn't a good idea either. As I tested, it still takes as good as approx two minutes, on the above complexity scale:

```
N = 100000;
test_m = zeros(3, N);
tic
for ii = (N - 1):-1:2
    test_m(:, ii) = [];
end
toc
% result: 105.436595 seconds. 
% This was run on a different machine than the previous examples.
% But is still enough evidence that dynamically resizing a big matrix is a BAD idea.
```

So, end of the story: **Don't try to remove columns or rows in this way**, unless you have a really small matrix. For bulky matrices, always use preallocation instead.

Comment: Since MATLAB stores data in a [column-major](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f22019) (columnwise) numbering scheme, removing columns should be more efficient.

Comment: @rahnema1 thanks. But reallocation of memory is inevitable is it?

Comment: Not necessarily ! It may use different approaches based on type of indexing.For example removing the first column only needs single call of [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) without reallocation. Or in a more optimized way it may not need memmove and use an offset to represent the start of data.

Comment: @rahnema1 unfortunately, as I tested it out, this is not the case. It took as good as at least dozens of seconds to perform the column removal.

Comment: It is better to provide results of your test. For example one test that removes the first column and other test that removes the last column and the same test for the first and the last row.

Comment: @rahnema1 Added. Actually it might even be worse than removing rows.

Comment: [Here](http://rextester.com/AXJND58948) is an online test in Octave that shows that column removal is more efficient than row removal.

Comment: @rahnema1 thanks. That said, it's still outperformed by preallocating.

Comment: I can not understand how removing columns/rows can be related to preallocation.

Comment: @rahnema1 maybe a better wording would be "preallocate the array, and don't dynamically append/insert/remove columns/rows."

Comment: Somewhat related: [How can I efficiently remove zeroes from a (non-sparse) matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/738438/52738), [Deleting matrix elements by = `[]` vs reassigning matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12421345/52738)

Comment: @gnovice in the first post, it still resizes the matrix and this add to involve copying data in memory.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues here:

1. Whether memory gets allocated for the deletion
2. Row major vs column major memory access
3. The code examples
4. preallocating modifications vs removal?

1) Without using mex, you have no control over whether matrix removal uses the same memory or not. However, you can tell if it happens or not. One approach would be to write something in mex. Alternatively you can activate `format debug`

```
N = 100000;
test_m = zeros(3, N);
t = evalc('disp(test_m)');
disp(t(1:100))
test_m(:,2:N-1) = [];
disp(t(1:100))
```

This yields the output

```
Structure address = 1259f6da0
m = 3
n = 100000
pr = 15d6d2020
pi = 0
  Columns 1 through 9

     0 

Structure address = 1259f6b70
m = 3
n = 2
pr = 608001c95320
pi = 0
     0     0
     0     0
     0

     0
```

Note that to keep the display reasonable I capture the output of displaying the variable and then only show part of it. This output, particularly `pr` (pointer to real data) indicates that reallocation occurred. I wasn't able to find any situation where reallocation didn't occur.

2) As mentioned in some of the comments and alluded to in the question, memory is stored as column-major. Thus when you delete a column it might be more efficient than deleting a row ...

3) I'm not entirely sure if the code examples are realistic but it makes a lot more sense to remove all columns or rows in one go. This occurs really quickly.

```
N = 100000;
test_m = zeros(3, N);
test_m(:,2:N-1) = [];
```

4) Finally, I'm not sure what your wording refers to with preallocating for modifications vs removal. Big picture it is probably best to avoid removing rows or columns in a loop. Instead hold onto an array that indicates which columns or rows should be removed and then do it in one pass.

Comment: Nice work! It is theoretically possible to remove rows or columns in-place, but I’m sure it’s easier to create a new matrix and copy the data over. Did you try removing the last column? That wouldn’t require any data copy at all. But maybe they didn’t bother special-casing that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried that too and I was surprised to see that the pointer changed. I've done something similar in mex using mxRealloc to truncate and I seem to remember it almost always keeps the same pointer.

Comment: You can just change the dimensions inplace in a mex routine to remove trailing columns. It will be fast but the memory for the trailing columns is still allocated. The problem with any inplace approach is (as usual) you can screw up other variables if there is any reference sharing going on (i.e., variables sharing the mxArray header). And for later versions of MATLAB the original mxArray pointer doesn't even get passed into the mex routine (a pointer to a shared data copy gets passed).